# Use function calls or constants when propmpted for text

Tags: org-mode

During my regular reviews, I use the following org-mode matching query:

```
SCHEDULED<="<2018-05-31>"/!
```

(it's actually much, much longer, but it contains that).

However, I need to change and adapt the query every month. I'd like to write something like:

```
SCHEDULED<=end_of_may/!
```

Or even just:

```
SCHEDULED<=end_of_current_month/!
```

This could be done easily if I could use pre-defined constants or functions when prompted for text to match, which could be defined in my file prelude or `.emacs` configuration file. However, I tried to use functions (`substring`) when prompted for text using sparse tree matching, and that did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about customizing the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` as described in the manual section relating to sparse-trees?  https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-trees.html

Comment: @lawlist I think `org-agenda-custom-commands` only assigns key sequences to specific tag-searches. I am afraid that it does not solve the problem of evaluating elisp expressions within the tag search. Please elaborate on the topic if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

We can introduce a new syntax element to evaluate lisp forms in a tag/property-search
by an `filter-args` advice of `org-tags-expand`. Let us borrow the syntax from interactive regular expression search `query-replace-regexp`:
`\,` is followed by a lisp expression that is evaluated.
For the main part of `org-make-tags-matcher` the prefix-operator `\,` together with the following lisp expression is replaced by `princ` of the evaluation result of the lisp expression.

While there is no full parser yet for tag searches we use the ppss parser of elisp.

Note, that we give the minus sign `-` punctuation syntax.
So you cannot evaluate a variable `foo-bar` by `\,foo-bar`. You have to use something like `\,(identity foo-bar)` for that special case.

```el
(defvar org-parse-tag-syntax-table nil
  "Syntax table for parsing MATCHes for tag searches.")

(setq org-parse-tag-syntax-table
      (with-syntax-table (make-syntax-table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- ".")
    (syntax-table)))

(defun org-tags-expand-filter-args-ad (args)
  "Allow lisp expressions by the \\,-operator in MATCH argument of `org-tags-expand'.
Use it as a filter argument advice for `org-tags-expand'."
  (let ((match (car args)))
    (if (stringp match)
    (save-match-data
      (with-temp-buffer
        (setq words-include-escapes nil)
        (insert match)
        (set-syntax-table org-parse-tag-syntax-table)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while
        (progn
          (skip-chars-forward "\\s \t\n")
          (if (or (looking-at "\\\\,")
                (looking-back "\\\\," (line-beginning-position)))
            (let* ((b (match-beginning 0))
               (bExpr (goto-char (match-end 0)))
               (e (progn
                (forward-sexp)
                (point))) ;; The doc string of `forward-sexp' does nothing say about the return value:-(.
               (formStr (buffer-substring bExpr e)))
              (delete-region b e)
              (insert (princ (eval (read formStr)))))
            (forward-sexp))
          (null (eobp))))
        (cons (buffer-string) (cdr args))
        ))
      args)))

(advice-add 'org-tags-expand :filter-args #'org-tags-expand-filter-args-ad)

(defun beginning_of_next_month ()
  "Return beginning of next month as org-date string in double quotes."
  (let ((decoded-time (decode-time (current-time))))
    (cl-loop for i from 0 below 3 do ;; indexes of SEC MINUTE HOUR
         (setf (nth i decoded-time) 0))
    (setf (nth 3 decoded-time) 1)
    (setf (nth 4 decoded-time) (1+ (mod (nth 4 decoded-time) 12))) ;; increment month
    (format "\"%s\"" (format-time-string (car org-time-stamp-formats) (apply #'encode-time decoded-time)))))
```

The above lisp code is tested with the org-file below and with the following versions of the software:

`emacs-version`
25.1.50.2




`org-version`
9.1.6

```org
#+TODO: WAITING
* Test Cases
**  WAITING some waiting work item                                      :work:
SCHEDULED: <2018-05-14 Mon>

**  WAITING second waiting work item                                    :work:
SCHEDULED: <2018-06-14 Mon>

* Query run via elisp
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
(org-match-sparse-tree nil "TODO=\"WAITING\"+SCHEDULED<\\,(beginning_of_next_month)+work")
#+END_SRC
```